# Are my #include files broken?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, wifi

I have been trying to use ioctl to get the state of my wifi connection, but have run into a problem: whenever i do `#include <linux/wireless.h>`, gcc generates lots of errors, e.g.

```
/usr/include/linux/wireless.h:869:18: error: field ‘src_addr’ has incomplete type
struct sockaddr src_addr;
                ^
/usr/include/linux/wireless.h:880:18: error: field ‘bssid’ has incomplete type
struct sockaddr bssid;
                ^
```

and many more similar ones. What does this mean? What do I do? Does it matter that I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM?

In case it helps, my code is simply:

```
#include <linux/wireless.h>
int main() { return 0; }
```

and I am compiling with `gcc thing.c`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the include of sockaddr.
You have to include:

```
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
```

Comment: Perfect. What is netinet/in.h?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/netinetin.h.html   The <netinet/in.h> header defines the in_addr structure that includes at least the following member:


in_addr_t      s_addr

The <netinet/in.h> header defines the sockaddr_in structure that includes at least the following member:


sa_family_t    sin_family
in_port_t      sin_port
struct in_addr sin_addr
unsigned char  sin_zero[8]